# Get InnerXML / InnerText from ChildNodes with specific name. Best Practice

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-parsing

I have an XML that looks like this (shortned)

```
 <TrainingCenterDatabase>
  <Activities>
    <Activity Sport="Running">
      <Id>2014-04-28T23:54:41.000Z</Id>
      <Lap StartTime="2014-04-28T23:54:41.000Z">
        <TotalTimeSeconds>284.957</TotalTimeSeconds>
        <DistanceMeters>1000.0</DistanceMeters>
        <MaximumSpeed>4.160999774932861</MaximumSpeed>
        <Calories>67</Calories>
        <AverageHeartRateBpm>
           <Value>152</Value>
        </AverageHeartRateBpm>
        <MaximumHeartRateBpm>
           <Value>162</Value>
        </MaximumHeartRateBpm>
        <Intensity>Active</Intensity>
        <TriggerMethod>Manual</TriggerMethod>
  </Lap>
  <Lap>
     SAME STUFF HERE
 </Lap>
</Activity>
  <Activities>
 </TrainingCenterDatabase>
```

And I'm extracting the information this way:

```
        XmlNodeList lapList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Lap");

        activity = new Activity();

        foreach (XmlNode lap in lapList)
        {
            var split = new Lap
            {
                StartTime = DateTime.Parse(lap.Attributes[0].Value),
                LapDistance = ConvertToDouble(lap.ChildNodes.Item(1).InnerXml),
                LapMaximunSpeed = ConvertToDouble(lap.ChildNodes.Item(2).InnerXml),
                LapCalories = ConvertToInt(lap.ChildNodes.Item(3).InnerXml),
                LapAverageHeartRate = ConvertToInt(lap.ChildNodes.Item(4).InnerText),
                LapMaximumHeartRate = ConvertToInt(lap.ChildNodes.Item(5).InnerText),
            };
```

My question is, Is there a way to make this less error prone? Like (referencing the element name?):

```
LapDistance = ConvertToDouble(lap.ChildNodes.Item["DistanceMeters"].InnerXml),
```

What is the best practice for this kind of scenario?

Comment: Any reasons not to use XmlSerialization or LINQ to XML?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SelectSingleNode()` with proper XPath string as argument to select child node by the node name, for example :

```
LapDistance = ConvertToDouble(lap.SelectSingleNode("DistanceMeters").InnerXml)
```

Null checking required if you're not sure all `<Lap>` node has corresponding child element.